# Why is hook.data not persisted to the database using PATCH?

Tags: feathersjs

Well, I'm new to *feathersjs* and I'm right now trying to port a small *express* experiment to it. The *internal* stuff works well so far, I can **create** a database entry for a scaffolded service and it's persisted. Nice.

Now I tried to use *postman* to send an unauthenticated **patch** to the server, and the changes are not persisted. That must be something really stupid, but I'm not seeing it in the moment.

This is an extract from affected the *hooks*:

```
const updateLocation = function () {
  return function (hook) {
    if (hook.params.query.latitude !== undefined && hook.params.query.longitude !== undefined) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        lookup({
          latitude: parseFloat(hook.params.query.latitude),
          longitude: parseFloat(hook.params.query.longitude)
        }, (info) => {
          hook.data = Object.assign(hook.data, info)
          resolve(hook)
        })
      })
    } else {
      return hook
    }
  }
}
```

To remove everything which might keep tricking me, I placed it directly in the **patch** *before* hook:

```
module.exports = {
  before: {
    all: [],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [
      disallow('external')
    ],
    update: [
      disallow('external')
    ],
    patch: [
      updateLocation()
    ],
    remove: []
  },
  after: {
    all: [],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [
      hook => console.log(hook.data)
    ],
    remove: []
  }
```

If I call **PATCH** with *latitude* and *longitude*, I'd expect *latitude* and *longitude* (and some additional values computed by the *lookup* method) to be replaced in the database entry. The *after* hook prints the calculated values to the console, but they never find their way to the database.

So isn't **PATCH** meant to do what I expect? Or didn't I get some important conceptional idea?

Comment: That looks like it should work. What database are you using?

Comment: I'm using the mongoose connector. So the data is persisted in a local running mongodb.

Comment: The only reason I can think of would be that Mongoose removes fields that are not in the model definition.

Comment: Hmm. They are in the model definition. I even tried completely without any schema, but it didn't help either.

Comment: Ah. I guess I found it. If there's one previously non existing field in the patch (in the schema, but not in the DB entry to be patched), the complete patch seems to be rejected silently. If there are just fields in the patch that already exist in the DB, it works.

Not sure if this is a bug.

Comment: You probably want to try changing the `lookup` method to use promises or `async/await`. The callback has an unusual signature (usually Node callbacks always have the error first which has to be rejected in the error case).

Comment: I can change this, sure. But the problem occurs *after* the lookup is done and all the hooks have been processed. Additionally `lookup` has it's own try/catch for historical reasons, so it should always return. I don't see why this will help in this case. The workaround is currently to preset all possible values in the DB object initially. Which is odd. I'd expect `PATCH` to be able to change uninitialized values, too. `UPDATE` is a no go at this position, because the caller will not be allowed to update the complete object.